# What is the Newtonian gravitational potential for a fluid element?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Currently reading [Poisson and Will](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Gravity.html?id=PZ5cAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) and looking at conserved quantities within the framework of a fluid element. I'm looking at a section on energy of a fluid system. When it comes time to defining the gravitational potential energy of a fluid element the expression is given by

$$\Omega (t) \equiv -\frac{1}{2} \int \rho U \; d^3x = -\frac{G}{2} \int\frac{\rho \rho'}{|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|}d^3x'd^3x, $$

where mass density, Newtonian gravitational potential, particle position and position of gravitational source are given by $\rho$, $U$, $\mathbf{x}$, $ \mathbf{x}'$ respectively.

**Question:** 
What is the deal with the factor of a half? My intuition is telling that the integral on the right is completely symmetric about $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{x}'$ and somehow is generating a 2 like what happens with odd and even definite integrals but I'm not entirely convinced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two particles exerting a force on each other, they both move. The factor $\frac12$ can be thought of as a "reduced mass" term.

Comment: So performing the integration of the force from one particle on another - - and them performing the same calculation we are "doubling" up so to speak? That's the reason for the half?

Comment: Yes I think that's exactly it. When you do the double integral, each particle gets counted twice... once as $x$ and cone again as $x'$.